# PHP | Image not loading from File

Tags: html, windows, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am attempting to load an Image from the local directory into my PHP file. However, it doesn't seem to load.

Here is my code:

```
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <img class="logo" src="images/logoDarkBlue.png" alt="img">
    
    <?php 
      echo "<img class='logo' src='images/logoDarkBlue.png' alt='img'>"; 
    ?>

    <form>
      <input type="text" class="nav-search" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="log-in">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i> &nbsp;<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i> &nbsp;Terms & Policies</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i> &nbsp;Log In / Sign Up</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Here is my entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- EXTERNAL CSS -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"> -->
  <style>
    <?php include "css/index.css" ?>
  </style>

  <!-- EXTERNAL SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/....." crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav-bar">
    <img class="logo" src="images/logoDarkBlue.png" alt="img">
    
    <?php 
      echo "<img class='logo' src='images/logoDarkBlue.png' alt='img'>"; 
    ?>

    <form>
      <input type="text" class="nav-search" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="log-in">
        <i class="fa-regular fa-user"></i> &nbsp;<i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i> &nbsp;Terms & Policies</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-question"></i> &nbsp;Log In / Sign Up</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.log-in')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to add the image using the traditional HTML syntax. Following this, I have tried to dynamically insert the image using PHP. However neither have worked. I have included both attempts in my code.

Paths:
Webserver Root:

> C:\Users\sat\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Project\DiscussIt\app\public

Images Folder:

> C:\Users\sat\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Project\DiscussIt\app\public\images

[image: Showing Paths]

NGINX Config:

```
server{
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /app/public;
  index index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml File:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "test"
      POSTGRES_USER: "testUser"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pg-admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=test@gmail.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
      - PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=5050
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
volumes:
  data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

RUN set -ex \
  && apk --no-cache add \
    postgresql-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pgsql
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252361/discussion-on-question-by-satanshu-mishra-php-image-not-loading-from-file); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forwarding all `.php` requests to FPM (your `app` service) but have not included the non-PHP files in your NGINX server.

Really all you're missing is a matching volume mount under the `webserver` service

```yml
  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./app:/app
```

Comment: That fixed it! Would you be able to give me a brief explanation of what adding ` - ./app:/app` actually did to fix the issue?

Comment: You started NGINX without anything present at `/app/public` so when it tried to serve `/images/logoDarkBlue.png`, it looked in `/app/public/images/logoDarkBlue.png` and found nothing